# How to apply dynamic content with dynamic content on page? Ionic 3 & angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, dynamic-programming

I'm working on an ionic 3 app.

So I already have a page that has data that is dynamic (The data pulls fine i.e. names and page). If you look at the code you'll notice that each "childStuff" has the same "childPage". My question is how do I get each "childStuff" to determine what is shown on "childPage"?

A real life example would be each of these "childStuff" is the name of a city and that city has information about it. "childPage" is layed out exactly the same for the data of each "childStuff". So what I want is when I tap (for example) Miami, "childPage" shows "Miami, X number of people live here." But when I tap Cleveland, "childPage" shows "Cleveland, XA number of people live here."

So basically I want the parent page to be able to say "When 'childStuff(instance 1) is tapped show the information pertaining to 'childStuff(instance 1) on 'childPage'"

Does that make sense?

Typescript - HTML

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { NewPage } from '../new/new';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  childStuff: Array<{name: string, childPage: any}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.childStuff= [
        {
          name: 'new',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new2',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new3',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new4',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new5',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new6',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new7',
          childPage: NewPage
        },{
          name: 'new8',
          childPage: NewPage
        }
      ];
  }

  goToNewPage(page) {
    //push another page onto the history stack
    //causing the nav controller to animate the new page in
    this.navCtrl.push(page.childPage);
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let c of childStuff" (click)="goToNewPage(c)">
 <a>
 <div>
 <p>{{c.name}}</p>
 </div>
 </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the beauty of a component-based framework is to have a lot of reusable components. You don't want to have a separate components for each city. You'd simply have the same CityPage and just pass params to the navCtrl.push() method:

```
goToNewPage(params) {
    this.navCtrl.push(CityPage, params);
}
```

And on the CityPage you'd handle the input params and structure your view accordingly.

```
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  template: `
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>City Page</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>I'm the other page!</ion-content>`
})
class CityPage {
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     let city = navParams.get('city');
     let population = navParams.get('population');
  }
}
```

This will help: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

**UPDATE**
In your parent component you can store parameters:

```
this.childStuff= [
    {
      city: 'Miami',
      population: 500000
    },{
      city: 'Cleaveland',
      population: 40000
    }
  ];
```

Comment: That solves getting data onto the CityPage but it's not dynamic anymore is it? Because if I tap cleveland, how does it differentiate between the cleveland data and the miami data in one navCtrl.push?

Comment: Thank you! I got it working however, instead of "let city" I used "this.city"

goToCampusPage(c) {
    //push another page onto the history stack
    //causing the nav controller to animate the new page in
    this.navCtrl.push(BloomingtonPage, {
      'name': c.name,
      'population': c.population
    });
  }

Comment: That's great, as long as it's working! :D Do you mind accepting and upvoting the answer so that other people could use the answer for solving their similar problems?